# QGIS Server Adding a virtual layer

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server, qgis-3, virtual-layer

All my layers in the qgs-project-file are working fine as WMS-layers, but I only can't provide the virtual layer.
The virtual layer is an ODBC-Connection of an Access-Database which contains one column with polygons as WKT and works like a charm.
My QGIS-server version is 3.4.4-2

Isn't it possible to provide a virtual layers via the QGIS-server as a WMS?

Or is there a solution?